# Many Java threads downloading content from web - but not saturating the bandwidth

Tags: java, multithreading, web-crawler, jsoup, router

A while back I tried implementing a crawler in Java and left the project for a while (made a lot of progress since). Basically I have implemented a crawler with circa 200-400 threads, each thread connects and downloads the content of one page (simplified for clarity, but that's basically it):

```
// we're in a run() method of a truely generic Runnable.
// _url is a member passed to the Runnable object beforehand.

Connection c = Jsoup.connect(_url).timeout(10000);

c.execute();

Document d = c.response().parse();

// use Jsoup to get the links, add them to the backbone of the crawler
// to be checked and maybe later passed to the crawling queue.
```

This works. The problem is I only use a very small fraction of my internet bandwidth. Having the ability to download at >6MB/s, I've identified (using NetLimiter and my own calculations) that I only use about 1MB/s **at best** when downloading pages sources.

I've done a lot of statistics and analyses and it is somewhat reasonable - **if** the computer cannot efficiently support over ~400 threads (I don't know about that also, but a larger number of threads seems to be ineffective) and each connection takes about 4 seconds to complete, then I'm supposed to download 100 pages per second which is indeed what happens. The bizarre thing is that many times while I run this program, the **internet connection is completely clogged** - neither I nor anyone else on my wifi connection can access the web normally (when I'm only using 16%! which does **not** happen when downloading other files, say movies).

I've spent literally weeks calculating, analyzing and collecting various statistics (making sure all threads are operating with VM monitor, calculating mean run time for threads, excel charts...), before coming here, but I've ran out of answers. I wonder if this behavior could be explained. I realize there's a lot of "ifs" in this question, but it's the best I can do without it turning into an essay.

My computer specs are i5 4460 with 8GB DDR3-1600 and a 100Mb/s (effectively around 8MB/s) internet connection, connected directly via LAN to the crawler. I'm looking for general directions - where else should I look 
(I mean obvous stuff that are clear to experienced developers and not myself) in order to either:

1. Improve the download speed (maybe not Jsoup? different number of threads? I've already tried using selectors instead of threads and it was slower), or:
2. Free up the internet when I'm running this program.

I've thought about the router itself (Netgear N600) limiting the number of outgoing connections (seems odd), so I'm saturating the number of connections, and not the bandwidth, but couldn't figure out if that's even possible.

Any general direction / advice would be warmly welcomed :) feel free to point out newish mistakes, that's how I learn.

Amir.

Comment: I would probably have a separate thread pool for downloading and another one for parsing. Parsing is CPU-bound, and thus having more parsers threads than cores is likely to slow things down, whereas you probably want the downloading pool to be sized dynamically, with the pool generally being much bigger than the pool of parsers. This isn't necessarily going to solve your problem, but it makes tuning a lot easier.

Comment: I would blame it on the router and probably on your provider. This kind of program runs better on a server at a (virtual) server hoster . The hosters has a diferent connection (faster, simetric) to the Internet than residents.

Comment: Also, if you're downloading many small pages, then the HTTP overhear might as well double or triple your actual bandwidth use.

Comment: @PeterMmm It is also possible that when you saturate the number of connections, you can't make DNS lookups any more, or at least I've seen this on a few routers too.

Comment: Well, 400 threads are indeed not the best idea. A modern approach would be to use [Java NIO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) for input multiplexing. here's a [tutorial for newbies](http://adblogcat.com/asynchronous-java-nio-for-dummies/)

Comment: Thank you all for replying (especially when the question is somewhat vague). I have answers for you if you want to follow up, I'll write them in separate comments.

Comment: @biziclop - the parsing is extremely quick - it takes about 0.1% - 1% of the time it takes to download the page. So the parsing phase seems to not be significant. I would agree that separating those makes sense, but it is a major design change. Thank you though for your thoughts.

Comment: @PeterMmm - I agree it might be a problem, but I don't want to blame "force major" since in my experience, many times it's my fault, not the hardware / prodiver's one :) Since I am able to download movies / music / files at 5MB/s, I don't understand why I'd be limited by this process (maybe it's the number of independent connections). The DNS thing seems interesting - I thought about managing the connections myself and keep a repository of IP addresses. If I'm doing something like: Socket s = new Socket("1.1.1.1", 80), then I would NOT have to do DNS lookup. Is that correct?

Comment: @user3159253 - I thought about that too and tried it, used selectors and custom SocketChannel objects to get responses from different hosts. It worked a lot slower unfortunately. Spent 2 days configuring that.

Comment: @amirkr In that case I wouldn't bother with separating them either.

Comment: One thing you can try though is to set up a web server on the same machine, fill it with some files, limit its speed to what you'd realistically expect from the target systems (Apache has several modules that do this) and point your crawler at it. If it fails in a similar way, the error is definitely in your program's concurrency handling. If it doesn't, it's probably something network-related which you can either do something about or not.

Comment: @biziclop I haven't thought of trying that. Thank you, it seems like a good test to conduct.

Comment: Why not using a framework like crawler4j or apache nutch? You could compare the throughput against your code (at least for crawler4j) very easy.

Comment: @rzo thank you, I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not DNS resolutions, as creating the connections with an IP address (I stored all addresses in advance then used those) resulted in the exact same response times and bandwidth use. Nor was it the threads issue.

I suspect now it was the netlimiter program's "fault". I've measured directly the number of bytes received and outputted these to disk (I've done this before but apprantly I've made some changes in the program). It seems I'm really saturating the bandwidth. Also, when switching to HttpUrlConnection objects instead of Jsoup, the netlimiter program does show a much larger bandwidth usage. Perhaps it has some issue with Jsoup. 
I'm not sure this was the problem, but empirically, the program downloads *a lot* of data. So I hope this helps anyone who might encounter a similar issue in the future.